# Custom completion in shell

Tags: c, linux, bash, tab-completion

I need to develop a utility that will take command line arguments as follows:

```
$ lsm  -g <group> -t <type> -d <device>
```

My project manager wants that when we type any argument like `lsm -g` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, then a function will be called to run a database query and fetch help for the user about the value of the option.

Similar to how terminal behaves in this case:

```
$ cd <tab>
.bash_history                   .local/
.bash_logout                    .log-report.log.swp
.bash_profile                   .macromedia/
.bashrc                         .mozilla/
.cache/                         Music/
.config/                        .mysql_history
.dbus/                          .nautilus/
Desktop/                        .opera/
Documents/                      .orc/
Downloads/                      .p2/
.eclipse/                       Pictures/
```

I have tried these approaches:

1. Use `fork()` to create a child to call the help function.
2. Use `execv()` to run a help function using a seperate binary.

But both require that `lsm` be running.

I'm not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Doesn't pressing tab in bash only do filename completion?  Is there any other bash command that does specifically command line completion?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah bash has an entire framework for custom completion - if the OP confirms he is using bash I can post an answer with some relevant information. Look in /etc/completion.d or /etc/bash_completion.d on your system (not all systems provide any by default though)

Comment: Google for custom bash completion. [Here is a question with answers from SuperUser](http://superuser.com/questions/289539/custom-bash-tab-completion)

Comment: Dear!!!! My problem is I need a solution so that after binary name<lms> if a option <-g> is specified and <tab-tab> is pressed then a funciton called `help(g)` should be called. This will show the group option available(A query from database) and then user pick one of them a d he will continue to type the other option too.(Without program to quit)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on your program to do the completion instead of the shell. The problem is that you need to make the shell run the program when pressing [Tab] which I doubt will work out in any way -- as this is something you cannot modify (afaik) with the shell.
You could however make the program run with ./binary_name and then create your own prompt which then can listen to [Tab] and provide completion.

Comment: Did you try clish? You can take a look at http://clish.sourceforge.net and see if it can help here.

Answer (score 1):

As various commentators have noted, tab-completion is implemented in the shell, not in the program which is about to be executed.

Most shells have frameworks for implementing custom tab-completion. In the case of `bash`, it is implemented with the help of the `readline` library. There is extensive documentation in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion) and there are a variety of tutorials kicking around the internet, such as [this one from Debian](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2) (not an endorsement, just the result of a quick Google search).